# react js how to add a button in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i am trying to add a button to the end of props.text but using this code puts [object Object] to the end of the text instead of the "set lines" button

```
function UnchangedText(props) {
  const setLines = <button>Set Lines</button>;
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <span></span>
      <pre>{
        props.text.includes("\\n") 
        ? props.text + setLines
        : props.text
      }</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function UnchangedText(props) {
  const setLines = <button>Set Lines</button>;
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <span></span>
      <pre>{
        props.text.includes("\\n") 
        ? <>{props.text}  {setLines} </>
        : props.text
      }</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If `.includes("\\n")` won't work, try `.includes(\`\n\`)`